# How to get the filetype of an url string inside a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I have two initialization methods: `initXML(url)` and `initJSON(url)`, which accept an url parameter. The parameter must be an url string that points to an XML or JSON file depending on the function.

What I want to do is to have just one method called `init(url)` which accepts an url parameter and then calls `initXML()` or `initJSON()` based on the filetype of the url parameter string.

*e.g. if the url parameter is something like `'content/file.json'` call initJSON(), if it is `'other/file.xml'` call initXML(), if another filetype return an error.*

How can I know this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```
function init(url)
{
    if ( url.match(/\.json$/i) )
    {
        initJSON(); 
    }
    else if ( url.match(/\.xml$/i) )
    {
        initXML();
    }
    else
    {
        throw "Unknown file type";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A *very* quick way of doing it would be to assume that the only period in your URL is at the end, just before the file type:

```
var type = url.split('.');
type = type[1];
```

Then the `type` variable would be either `'json'` or `'xml'`.

A more foolproof system would be to use regular expressions:

```
var type = /\.(xml|json)$/.exec(url);
type = type[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression like this:

```
var isJSON = /\.json$/i;
var isXML = /\.xml$/i;
if( isJSON.test( url ) == true )
  initJSON()
else if( isXML.test( url ) == true )
  initXML()
else
  return( 'error' );
```